# Semop: When decreasing a set of semaphores are all decremented at once or does it block on first failure?

Tags: c, unix, semaphore

So if I have a *semaphore set* `semid` with `num_of_sems` semaphores and a *sembuf* `*deleter_searchers_down`

```
struct sembuf *deleter_searchers_down 
                        = malloc(sizeof (*deleter_searchers_down) * num_of_sems);
for (i = 0; i < num_of_sems; ++i) {
            (deleter_searchers_down + i)->sem_op = -1;
            (deleter_searchers_down + i)->sem_num = i;
            (deleter_searchers_down + i)->sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
        }
semop(semid, deleter_searchers_down, num_of_sems);
```

The call to semop will attempt to lower all semaphores in the set at once or will it block once it attempts to lower the first semaphore that is 0 and continue after some other process ups that particular semaphore?

Comment: Well semaphores do exactly what you say ,that is ,when they are lowered, if they are 0 they block the process.

Comment: Read the question carefully plz - will semop attempt to lower all of the set and block on all of the zero ones or will it block on the first (first ?) encountered 0

Comment: You can specify IPC_NOWAIT to return immediately on failure. See:http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/semop.html

Comment: @RedX The link is relevant, IPC_NOWAIT is not. The question is if the one of the operations in the array that does not cause blocking is performed immediately, or if it's deferred and the operations are done all at once when the process is unblocked(cause one of the later operations in the array caused it to block in the first place)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No updates happen until all updates can proceed as a unit.

The POSIX specification could be clearer about this point, although it does say that `semop` is atomic.

On Linux, `semop(3)` in glibc is a simple wrapper around `semop(2)`.  The `semop(2)` manpage in turn says

> The set of operations contained in `sops` is performed in *array order*, and *atomically*, that is, the operations are performed either as a complete unit, or not at all.

The HP-UX `semop(2)` manpage is even clearer:

> Semaphore
>         array operations are atomic in that none of the semaphore operations
>         are performed until blocking conditions on all of the semaphores in
>         the array have been removed.

Comment: Thanks - does this mean that the process trying to down the semid will block on the first array element that is 0 and semop() will undo all the previous array elements downs() ?

Comment: This is up to the implementation.  As an example, the code in Linux ipc/sem.c (function `try_atomic_semop`) does something similar what you describe.  It tries the operations, and if any of them block, changes are undone.  But there is an important point: the updates are done while holding a lock on the semaphore set.  So the inconsistent state is not visible to any other task:  a task wishing to change the semaphore would first have to acquire the lock, and a task blocked on the semaphore is already asleep.  So in the end the operation is truly atomic.

Comment: Ok - thanks - a last point : there is no chance (implementation) the process calling semop will block on _all_ semaphores that are 0 ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, so feel free to correct me.  If multiple semaphores are 0 and cannot be acquired, the call to `semop` will block until this becomes possible.  `semop` will not return until the entire operation is complete.  If your question is about wasting CPU time, in recent Linux kernels the task is not scheduleable when on a semaphore wait queue: it will sleep and be woken once another task calls `semop` and changes the semaphore set.

Comment: I meant if it is possible for the process calling semop (as in the example given) to block on _all_ semaphores that are 0 - that is not only on the first (in array order) it encounters to be 0. So _instead_ of undoing the operation to block on all the ones that are 0 and wait for all of them - but when all of them become available not redo but just return. But this would contradict the role of semaphores (easy to think a counterexample if there are other processes uping the sems in semid).

Comment: So if `semid = (1,0,0)` - after calling semop I asked if it was possible to have `semid = (0,process in queue,process in queue)` - but apparently it is `semid = (1,process in queue,0)` after calling semop - right ?

Comment: The wait queue is per semid, not the individual semaphores.  In your example, semid = (1, 0, 0), and two processes try to decrement.  Both would be put on the wait queue.  Once all semaphores become available, the first task to call `semop` is woken, and returns from the `semop` call.  When the second task can proceed (all semaphores again available), it is woken and completes its call in turn.

Comment: Not so sure about this - imagine _another_ process calling `semop(semid,{-1,1,SEM_UNDO},1)` - that is calling down() only on the second semaphore of the set - it would not have to wait for the third. Are you sure it is per semid set in this case ? Anyway - for a process1 trying to lower the entire semid = (1,0,0) - what happens if after process1 calls semop process2 tries to down() the first semaphore ? I guess process2 succeeds - as the changes from process1 are undone

Comment: Ok - thanks - so process1 in the example above enters in the semid queue and when an up occurs the semop call is repeated - in case all of the sems were upped in the meantime. See my issue was that if process1 tries to down the whole set (`(1,0,0)`) and process2 tries to down sem2 - when sem2 is upped by process3 the FIFO queue will be process1, process2 - but process3 will block because of sem3=0 and process2 will happily proceed due to the undo - I hoped that process2 will be blocked - but cannot be. Thanks anyway

Comment: You are right.  The queue is per-semid to enforce FIFO order.  But when a semid is modified in any way, the queue is searched for any tasks that can be woken up.  This does mean that the current Linux implementation does not deal with the possibility of starvation (indeed, the comment at the top of the file says so).

Comment: You could not edit your comment so you deleted it and copied it heh ? :) - I replied to it - see my reply above

Comment: Sorry, I wrote a response, and then had some doubts, so I went back and re-read the code :)  Just didn't want to risk misleading you in case I got it wrong.  I actually had to retype the comment from memory.

Comment: So the example I gave with processes1,2,3 - is how it would go you think ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10245/discussion-between-g-inozemtsev-and-mr-and-mrs-d)