# semop - is it possible to increment a semaphores (in a set of two), whilst the second semaphore is getting blocked

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

I have two semaphores that should be changed atomically.

```
  union semun su;
  struct sembuf sb[2];
  int num = 2;

  semid = semget(num, 3, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0600);

  su.val = 1;
  semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, su);
  su.val = 0;
  semctl(semid, 1, SETVAL, su);

  sb[0].sem_num = 0;
  sb[0].sem_op  = 1; // signal
  sb[0].sem_flg = 0;

  sb[1].sem_num = 1;
  sb[1].sem_op  = -1; //wait
  sb[1].sem_flg = 0;

  semop(semid, sb, 2)
```

As you can see, one semaphore should `signal()`, and the other should `wait()`.

I read in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206501/semop-when-decreasing-a-set-of-semaphores-are-all-decremented-at-once-or-does-i) that if both of the semaphores are changed at once, and if there is one semaphore that get blocked, then it doesn't really changes the other - and all of the set is going to sleep.

In my implementation it is really important to me that:

1. Both of the operations of the two semaphores will happen atomically
2. If the second semaphore will be blocked, it won't matter to the first semaphore. Means that the first semaphore will `signal()` as supposed to, and the second will `wait()`...

I couldn't understand from the attached question if it is possible to do, and I'm not sure that there is an answer to that there...

So I wanted to ask if it possible

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 1):

> I read in this question that if both of the semaphores are changed at once, and if there is one semaphore that get blocked, then it doesn't really changes the other - and all of the set is going to sleep.

What the question deals is whether the set of semaphore operations happens atomically or not. The Answer rightly clarified it to be Atomic.

Instead of thinking this way

> "if both of the semaphores are changed at once"

Look at it this way

> "if both of the semaphores are changed **as one** "

I am sure , you will then appreciate the concept of atomicity.

So clearly in the above code doing this

```
semop(semid, sb, 2)
```

will perform operations of both the semaphore sb[0] and ab[1] **as a single operation** , regardless of what your intentions are.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this action will perform atomically. The problem is that, because one semaphore which belongs to the set is blocked, then (as I understood) the whole set is going to sleep. so the first semaphore's change doesn't really count yet...

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code sample is incorrect and does not make much sense. It should be instead:

```
sb[0].sem_num = 0;
sb[0].sem_op = 1; // signal
sb[0].sem_flg = 0;

sb[1].sem_num = 1;
sb[1].sem_op = -1; //wait
sb[1].sem_flg = 0;

semop(semid, sb, 2)
```

What you are describing is possible, and that's just 2 sequential operations:

```
sb[0].sem_num = 0;
sb[0].sem_op = 1; // signal
sb[0].sem_flg = 0;
semop(semid, sb, 1)

sb[0].sem_num = 1;
sb[0].sem_op = -1; // wait
sb[0].sem_flg = 0;
semop(semid, sb, 1)
```

After discussion in comments it looks like the question could be rephrased like this: can I make semop() atomic operation partially atomic? No you cannot, it is atomic. If you do not need multiple operations to be atomic, do not put them in one semop().

Comment: Thanks for the correction of `sb[1].sem_num = 1;` , But with your solution - these two operations are not perform atomically

Comment: If that two operations will perform atomically, then first operation will wait for second. If first one should not need to wait for second, why does it need to be atomic with second?

Comment: I want the operations to perform atomically, 
I want the first semaphore to `signal()`, and the second to `wait()` atomically, whilst if the one who does `wait()` get stuck, it doesn't matter for the first semaphore, his `signal()` should count, that's what I want to create

Comment: You either want them to perform atomically or you do not. Atomically here means 2 operations work as one. If first one does not depend on second there is no reason to put them both in one semop() call. Or please provide the reason why they need to be the way you want them.

Comment: I want them to perform atomically - without the possibility of context switch or anything while performing these operations, not because they depend on each other, but because of this is some part of an algorithm which they must perform atomically to preserve the algorithm correctness. This is my topic question, if it is possible to do

Comment: Provide your algorithm and show, why it depends on that. Otherwise this is just, I want something, but cannot explain what and why.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25440/discussion-between-hudac-and-slava)